# $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq \|x\|_{2}$ for all $x\in l_2$ and $\|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_1$ for $x\in l_1$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm getting ready for a midterm in my analysis class and was trying to solve this problem as part of my review. I was looking around, but couldn't find any solutions so I figured I'd ask here.

The definitions I'm working with are:

$l_p$ is the collection of sequences such that $x\in l_p$ if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x|^{p}<\infty$ and we have the the $p$-norm defined as $\|x\|_p = \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x|^{p}\right)^{1/p}$

We define $l_{\infty}$ as the collection of all bounded sequences under the norm $\|x\|_{\infty} = \sup_{n\geq 1}\{|x_n|\}$.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case, note that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^2 = |x_{i^\star}|^2+\sum_{i\neq i^\star}|x_i|^2 \geq |x_{i^\star}|^2\,,$$ where $i^\star$ is any fixed index. If you choose $i^\star$ to be the index such that $|x_{i^\star}|\geq |x_i|$ for all $i$, then you've just to take the square root.

The second case is equivalent to show that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^2\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|\right)^2.$$ Can you see why is it so?

First notice that for any $a\geq 0$, $b\geq 0$, $$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab\geq a^2+b^2\,.$$

Now fix $N>1$, can you generalise the previous result as
$$\sum_{i=1}^N |x_i|^2\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^N |x_i|\right)^2?$$

Maybe induction can help...

Once you've done so, it is enough to take the limit $N\to\infty$...